# Unable to print on network printer Ricoh Aficio MP C3001 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: printing, samba, 14.04, ricoh

After a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04 I'm no longer able to print using the Ricoh Aficio MP C3001 printer that is accessible via samba on the network. Job completes normally but nothing gets printed.

It requires user authentification and an additional user code. The user code was configured using `lpoptions -p printername -o UserCode=xxx` which correctly changes `~/.cups/lpoptions` with the user code. I also tried changing the ppd file with the custom user code instead of the predefined 100x values but this did not change the problem that I'm no longer able to print.

The printer gets detected and even seems to respond to a print job (it wakes up, but instead of printing, shuts down again). Printer works fine with the same settings using Windows and also previously worked with Ubuntu 13.10 and the same configuration.

Here is a (small) part of the cups error_log.

```
D [24/Apr/2014:10:58:24 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Active clients and dirty files"
D [24/Apr/2014:10:58:24 +0200] cupsd is not idle any more, canceling shutdown.
D [24/Apr/2014:10:58:24 +0200] [Client 19] POST / HTTP/1.1
D [24/Apr/2014:10:58:24 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Active clients and dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [24/Apr/2014:10:58:24 +0200] [Client 19] No authentication data provided.
D [24/Apr/2014:10:58:24 +0200] [Client 19] 2.0 CUPS-Get-Printers 6
D [24/Apr/2014:10:58:24 +0200] CUPS-Get-Printers
D [24/Apr/2014:10:58:24 +0200] [Client 19] Returning IPP successful-ok for CUPS-Get-Printers (no URI) from localhost
D [24/Apr/2014:10:58:24 +0200] [Client 19] Content-Length: 482
D [24/Apr/2014:10:58:24 +0200] cupsd is not idle any more, canceling shutdown.
D [24/Apr/2014:10:58:24 +0200] [Client 19] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_STATE_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODING_LENGTH, data_remaining=482, response=0x7fb6a5e8f410(IPP_IDLE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
D [24/Apr/2014:10:58:24 +0200] [Client 19] Writing IPP response, ipp_state=DATA, old wused=0, new wused=0
D [24/Apr/2014:10:58:24 +0200] [Client 19] bytes=0, http_state=0, data_remaining=0
D [24/Apr/2014:10:58:24 +0200] [Client 19] Waiting for request.
```

Troubleshooting guide did not help and printing a document does not give me any error messages.